# Python - Pandas - Remove only splits that only numeric but maintain if it have alphabetic

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a dataframe that have two values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Table_A112', 'Table_A_112']})
```

What I am trying to do is to remove the numeric digits in case of the split('_') only have numeric digits.
The desired output is:

```
Table_A112
Table_A_
```

For that I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib
from tabulate import tabulate
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Table_A112', 'Table_A_112']})
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.rstrip(string.digits)
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

But it gives me the following output:

```
Table_A
Table_A_
```

How can do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: what s expected for `Table_112_A` ?

Comment: In this case it should be 'Table__A'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Table_A112', 'Table_A_112', 'Table_112_avs']})

print(df)

        Col1
0     Table_A112
1    Table_A_112
2  Table_112_avs
```

---

```
df.Col1.str.replace(r'(?:^|_)(\d+)(?:$|_)', '_', regex=True)

0    Table_A112
1      Table_A_
2     Table_avs
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wXioa1/2)

Comment: OP wants a trailing underscore on the 2nd result. Maybe replace with `_`?

Comment: @yatu `Table_112_A` will yield `Table_A` but OP requests `Table__A` (see comments above).

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like:

```
s = df['Col1'].str.split('_',expand=True).stack()
s.mask(s.str.isdigit(), '').groupby(level=0).agg('_'.join)
```

Output:

```
0    Table_A112
1      Table_A_
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice , i should have use the stack too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a regex solution you can do using [`pandas.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and a positive lookbehind `r'(?<=_)\d+'`

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Table_A112', 'Table_A_112']})
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
df= df.replace(regex=r'(?<=_)\d+', value='')
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Which produces the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `str.replace` with capture group making the pattern much simpler

```
sample df

Out[1063]:
          Col1
0   Table_A112
1  Table_A_112
2  Table_111_B

df.Col1.str.replace(r'(_)\d+', r'\1')

Out[1064]:
0    Table_A112
1      Table_A_
2      Table__B
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```